# C# Threading Parallel.ForEach and DirectoryInfo Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, directoryinfo

I have a very simply Parallel.ForEach that calls the code below:

```
var maxDegree = new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5};
Parallel.ForEach(PList,maxDegree,fl =>
            {
                ProjectDirectoryProcessing pjp = new ProjectDirectoryProcessing();
                pjp.ProjectProcessor(fl);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        );

public class ProjectDirectoryProcessing
{

    public void ProjectProcessor(string rootDirectory)
    {
           DirectoryInfo Dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory);
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = Dinfo.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            FileInfo[] finfo = Dinfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (FileInfo f in finfo)
            {
                FileSize = FileSize + f.Length;
            }
            FileCount = finfo.Length;
            DirectoryCount = directories.Length;
    }
}
```

The problem is I run out of memory, I thought about GC.Collect() after the pjp.ProjectProcessor in the Parallel.ForEach but I'm not sure if this will work. The directories are extremely large and I'm not positive that cleaning those up will help all that much. What would be a good way to handle this?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do with the Files. `Directory.EnumerateFiles` could make a huge difference.

Comment: see edit, i'm just counting up the size of the directories and filecount, and Directory.EnumerateFiles causes a huge performance issue

Comment: What exactly is your application supposed to do? Can't you switch to a producer-consumer model and load folders one by one?

Comment: @Tudor I actually tried that method and the performance to that is drastic, the time for example went from 52 minutes above to around 4 hours.

Comment: @Mike: Were you using a single thread to lead the directories or multiple in parallel?

Comment: `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5` implies a RAID level 10 or so.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it also limits the number of parallels, i first tried without max and that just crashes, then i tried 10 and got OOM, then i tried 5 and it takes to long to do all the directories

Comment: Then keep the momentum going: Make it `MaxDegreeOfParallelism=1`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the problem with that is sometimes a directory will take 8 hours and the others 15 minutes, the idea is to get them all done within a 12 hour time period

Comment: @Mike : doing them in parallel will still not improve the total time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So you're telling me if i kick off 15 directories at one time, compared to kicking off 1 by 1 it won't affect total time?

Comment: @Mike: depends totally on the number of independent disks. Making 1 disk-head move all over the place only slows you down.

Comment: @HenkHolterman we're talking about a 100TB unix array here...

Comment: That piece of info was missing. Still, 5 might be too high. Experiment.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Heh, yeah that's a bit of info.  the OOM here is the main issue not so much the heads, I can simply request a bigger box but I have no control over the data inside of the folders, so I have to be able to manage the size of DirectoryInfo more than the MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Comment: @HenkHolterman In fact, me decreasing the amount of MaxDegreeOfParallelism is just a work around for negating the size of DirectoryInfo

Answer (score 0):

Calling GC manually won't help as GC should be automatically called before throwing an OutOfMemoryException.
One easy solution could be to compile the application as x64. Is this an option?

Comment: Not currently, I could request a test box and give it a shot, will that help that much?

Comment: For sure. I've been working with huge applications that could not fit on a x32 address space that worked perfectly fine on x64. You are not really running out of memory but address space.

Comment: Heres the thig isn't 4gb, 4gb?  Regardless if it's 32 or 64 bit, i thought the point of 64 bit was to access larger memory usage

Comment: It's more complex than that. You have 2Gb adress space per process. I had some memory process a while ago. Check this, is really well explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610552/how-can-i-get-an-outofmemoryexception-in-net